# How to print the CMOS time in seconds in C program?

Tags: c, linux

I have written a small program which was actually extracted from the linux source code. Please find my sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CMOS_READ(addr) ({ \
outb_p(0x80|addr,0x70); \
inb_p(0x71); \
})

#define outb_p(value,port) \
__asm__ ("outb %%al,%%dx\n" \
                "\tjmp 1f\n" \
                "1:\tjmp 1f\n" \
                "1:"::"a" (value),"d" (port))

#define inb_p(port) ({ \
unsigned char _v; \
__asm__ volatile ("inb %%dx,%%al\n" \
        "\tjmp 1f\n" \
        "1:\tjmp 1f\n" \
        "1:":"=a" (_v):"d" (port)); \
_v; \
})

#define outb(value,port) \
__asm__ ("outb %%al,%%dx"::"a" (value),"d" (port))


#define inb(port) ({ \
unsigned char _v; \
__asm__ volatile ("inb %%dx,%%al":"=a" (_v):"d" (port)); \
_v; \
})

int main(void)
{
        int val = 0;
        val  = CMOS_READ(0);
        printf("val = %d", val);
        return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine but on execution it is giving a seg fault.
Could somebody guide me on this?

Comment: That's more of an assembly program than a C program.

Comment: User programs cannot access I/O ports directly, that's kernel territory. Your SEGFAULT means exactly this: you access a SEGment you are not allowed to, it's your FAULT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have permissions to access the CMOS I/O ports. You would need to be running with CAP_SYS_RAWIO (usually as root, though you could also be using file capabilities), and call [ioperm(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ioperm.2.html) to request access to the CMOS I/O ports.

Also, `<sys/io.h>` defines I/O access macros, so you don't need to define them yourself.